# Pose Position & Rest Position are Different Though Character Not Posing

Tags: rigging

I'm having a problem trying to understand why my characters eye bones are moving to a different position in pose mode when the character isn't posing? Where the bones are in rest mode is where they should be in pose mode and object mode too. I tried to apply as rest pose but I get an error saying "Actions on this armature will be destroyed by the new rest pose..." and it doesn't let me do it. I tried applying the armature modifer and adding a new armature modifer, I also tried applying location, rotation and scale in object mode and I cannot figure out why these bones in pose mode don't stay in the same place when my character isn't posing. I tried going to blender forums and I found multiple people with this problem and I've already tried all the things recommended and I still don't know what to do.  If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate it, Thanks in advance

Here's a video of the problem
https://mega.nz/#!elF2UIKA!y7-iqlRqAHWo12IcPFXyAR1SMa6F-doeNLvABYb_jkw

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up having to do with me accidentally parenting the eyelid bones to the wrong bones. Once I parented everything exactly how the tutorial I'm watching said, I got the same exact result and things are working properly and now I can continue rigging the eyelids. Since I’ve done rigging before, I guess I got a little overconfident and skipped some parts of the video lol A good lesson to always be humble, learn, and take things one step at a time haha Thanks again!